# Is there a Java version of Clojure's or Scala's persistent immutable vector?

Tags: java, scala, collections, clojure, immutability

That is, immutable but data sharing with effectively O(1) indexing.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8575723/whats-a-good-persistent-collections-framework-for-use-in-java

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Karl Krukow extracted clojure data structures into [standalone library](https://github.com/krukow/clj-ds), so you can use it without bringing whole clojure to your project. There is also [pcollections](https://code.google.com/p/pcollections/) which has [TreePVector](https://pcollections.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/org/pcollections/TreePVector.html) implementation (with logarithmic time lookups).

Answer (score 3):

I made a library of persistent data structures for Java a couple of years back that may fit the bill:

https://github.com/mikera/mikera/tree/master/src/main/java/mikera/persistent

They are somewhat like the Clojure data structures, but with more of a Java flavour:

- Make full use of generics
- Support all the Java collection interfaces you would expect
- Include some handy specialised types (e.g. `RepeatList` for repeated occurences of the same value)

Comment: I use them a lot (whenever I don't want to pull in the whole of Clojure...), and maintain the code as open source. I think a few other people are using them. Basically, they are in a robust and usable state.

Answer (score 1):

Remember that Clojure, in the end, is just Java. As such you can just put Clojure's jar in your classpath and use its classes.

For instance, Clojure vectors are instances of `clojure.lang.PersistentVector`, maps are instances of `clojure.lang.PersistentArrayMap` and lists, instances of `clojure.lang.PersistentList`.

I haven't tried this in anger myself but that's probably the line I'd take if I wanted to use persistent data structures in Java.

Something like this could get you started:

```
import clojure.lang.PersistentVector;
...
ArrayList list = ...
PersistentVector myVector = PersistentVector.create(list);
// from here on, using myVector takes advantages of its persistent nature.
```

Obviously these classes were built with Clojure's API in mind, and not ease of use from Java - but it's certainly possible.

Comment: Thanks, but that is a heavyweight solution, and as you say the ease of use from Java is compromised.

Comment: I'm curious. What's your use case?

Comment: Having spent a year in Scala, not having what is effectively the default Scala collection is a bit painful! Guava helps with some functional constructs, but it's immutable collections are poor compared to Vector.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a Scala -> Java port: https://github.com/andrewoma/dexx