# is h2 a persistent alternative to java collections with disk backend

Tags: java, database-design, h2, bigdata

I'm still looking for Java Collections that are persistent and have comparable access times for performance. The Real data should stay on the disk but for faster access times I need a cache in the RAM so I can stream the content from the file to the main memory.

I read about h2 have such a cache function. Is there a option to cache the whole file on start up?

And can somebody say something about the performance?
Currently, I have more than 100.000 items in a Java HashMap (key value is custom class which contains a byte array).

Thank you!

Comment: Given sufficient work and tolerance for sufficient differences, almost any storage system can be used as an alternative to java collections.

Comment: Maybe you don't want to use anything else than H2, but you could look at http://infinispan.org/

Comment: This answer might also give you some good hints although it is from a while back: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8575723/whats-a-good-persistent-collections-framework-for-use-in-java

Comment: my main fear is, that a alternative have lower performance than a java collection

Comment: This is probably also interesting for you: [largecollections - a fast and persistent cache](http://www.bigsynapse.com/largecollections-a-fast-and-persistent-cache)

Answer (score 0):

Partially. The [H2 MVStore](http://h2database.com/html/mvstore.html) can be used as a persistent `java.util.Map`. But not as a list, stack, or so. The H2 Database is a relational database, with SQL and JDBC API, and with the latest version uses the MVStore as the default storage engine.

Other projects such as [MapDB](http://www.mapdb.org/) support similar features than the MVStore.