# Changing value in a map, the right way

Tags: java, functional-programming

Sorry, I don't think the title I wrote is correct and explains well what I'm asking, but at the moment I have not found better

I'm trying to change my approach from imperative to functional-programming in Java, sometime is easy but in other case no much... But I'm not giving up :)

I have a map of values that should be decreased of an amount calculated by a function, and for each input the are one or more functions that could be applied, what has been decreased by the previous function is "visible" to the next function, so something like that

```
    Map<String, Double> input = new HashMap<>() {{
        put("IN1", 100.0);
        put("IN2", 10.0);
    }};

    Map<String, List<Function<Double, Double>>> rules = Map.of(
            "IN1", List.of(value -> value / 10.0, value -> 80.0, value -> 10.0),
            "IN2", List.of(value -> 2.0),
            "IN3", List.of(value -> value / 5.0));
```

In imperative "style", I solve this using a function like that

```
    for (Map.Entry<String, List<Function<Double, Double>>> entry : rules.entrySet()) {
        String inName = entry.getKey();
        Double inValue = input.get(inName);
        if (inValue==null) continue;
        for (Function<Double, Double> function : entry.getValue()) {
            inValue -= function.apply(inValue);
            if (inValue <= 0F) break;
        }
        input.put(inName, inValue);
    }
```

What should be the right way in functional programming?

Thanks in advance :)

---

**EDIT**

The only solution I found is the following

```
    Map<String, Double> result = 
       input.entrySet().stream()
            .map(e -> calculator(e, rules.get(e.getKey())))
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(Pair::getKey, Pair::getValue));
```

First step is aggregate all rules by input and then iterate for each input and, using a recursive calculator function, create another map that will contain, for each input, the remaining value after function application

```
private static Pair<String, Double> calculator(Map.Entry<String, Double> input, List<Function<Double, Double>> entries) {
    double value = input.getValue();
    double result = calculator(value, entries.iterator());
    return Pair.of(input.getKey(), result);
}

private static double calculator(double value, Iterator<Function<Double, Double>> iterator) {
    if (!iterator.hasNext() || value<=0F) return value;
    Function<Double, Double> function = iterator.next();
    double cost = function.apply(value);
    return calculator(value-cost, iterator);
}
```

calculator is a recursive function, so the immutability rule is respected :)

Let me know if exists another solution!

Thanks in advance

Comment: FP environments usually offer "persistent" datastructures that have "modifiers" that don't change the original data but return a modified copy. For a Map, this would mean having `newMap = map.updated(key, newValue)`. This can be horribly inefficient, though, if you don't have specialized data structures that support it. Copying a complete hashmap for example wouldn't be great.

Comment: Maybe interesting: https://stackoverflow.com/q/8575723/14955

Comment: Thanks Thilo, you are right, the only solution I found at moment is rebuild another map using collectors, but I hope is not the only solution, because in this case I had to update a map repeatedly, and this is not a good solution IMHO :)

Comment: Why don't You define a second map say `resultMap`. If the key is in the `resultMap` -> calculate, if not take the key from the `inputMap` -> calculate. In either case the result goes to the `resultMap`.

Comment: Thanks Kaplan, more o less, this was my first solution, creating a second map, updated via collectors, but also in this case we are changing an object... Now I'm working to another solution, I'll post the answer in a while

Comment: Question updated :)

Comment: @marc0x71,  Why do you create a copy of `rules` by re-collecting it into `functions` map?

Comment: Just to have a list of function to be applied for every input, this simplify the next step ;)

Comment: No you are right, is not useful! :D I'll remove it, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A "brute-force" solution can look as follows:

```java
rules.entrySet().stream()
    .filter(e -> input.containsKey(e.getKey())) // skip keys missing in the input
    .forEach(e -> e.getValue().stream()
        .filter(f -> input.get(e.getKey()) > 0) // check the limit in input
        .forEach(
            f -> input.put(e.getKey(), input.get(e.getKey()) - f.apply(input.get(e.getKey())))
        )
    );

System.out.println(input); // {IN2=8.0, IN1=0.0}
```

A shorter version is based on `Map::computeIfPresent`:

```java
rules.entrySet().stream()
    .forEach(e -> e.getValue().stream()
        .forEach(
            f -> input.computeIfPresent( // if key is present in input
                e.getKey(), 
                (k, v) -> v > 0 ? v - f.apply(v) : v) // check the limit
        )
    );
```

Or filter the rules using `containsKey`, use `takeWhile` (Java 9+) and then apply `compute` to input:

```java
rules.entrySet().stream()
    .filter(e -> input.containsKey(e.getKey()))
    .forEach(e -> e.getValue().stream()
        .takeWhile(f -> input.get(e.getKey()) > 0)
        .forEach(
            f -> input.compute(e.getKey(), (k, v) -> v - f.apply(v))
        )
    );
```

---

**Update**
A better solution which does not modify the outside `input` map but creates a new map instead is based on `Collectors.toMap` and [`Stream::reduce (U identity, BiFunction<U,? super T,U> accumulator, BinaryOperator<U> combiner)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#reduce-U-java.util.function.BiFunction-java.util.function.BinaryOperator-) operations:

```java
Map<String, Double> result = input.entrySet()
        .stream()
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(
            Map.Entry::getKey, 
            e -> rules.getOrDefault(e.getKey(), Collections.emptyList())
                .stream()
                .reduce(
                    e.getValue(), // initial value from input
                    (res, fun) -> res > 0 ? res - fun.apply(res) : res, // accumulate
                    (res1, res2) -> res2 // combine
                )
        ));
System.out.println(result);  // {IN2=8.0, IN1=0.0}
```

Comment: Thanks Alex, but in this case your solution modifies the input map, so in this case we are violating the "immutability" rule of functional programming, is it right?

Comment: Original solution was also modifying the original `input` map, that's the reason I provided such implementation.

Comment: Yes it's true but in FP style you shouldn't ;) Take a look at the solution I found

Comment: @marc0x71, you may check the update, it is implemented in _pure_ FP style without side effect with the help of `reduce` operation.

Comment: Thanks Alex, it works and is implemented in pure functional style! I prefer the recursive mode, but is good also you solution :)